# TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined: dynamically put key name

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make key part of the assignment dynamic so i tried this.

```
var contentList = Object.keys(content)[0];
$scope.model.currentLoadedContent[contentList] = content[Object.keys(content)[0]]
```

for 2nd line, `$scope.model.currentLoadedContent[contentList]`  i am getting this error. `"TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined"` Any solution for this ? [image]

Comment: Put a debugger in there and find out what's undefined.  No way for us to know from this code snippet.  Also, if you are going to define `contentList`, you should used it in both places.  Otherwise there is no benefit to caching the selector.

Comment: @jmargolisvt it's about contentList. individually it has value but this full statement become undefined $scope.model.currentLoadedContent[contentList] . See attchment

Answer (score 0):

This problem got solved by this way

```
var contentList = Object.keys(content)[0];
$scope.model.currentLoadedContent = {};
$scope.model.currentLoadedContent[contentList] = content[Object.keys(content)[0]]
```

as currentLoadedContent was undefined during the time of assignment.